# Grouping and Dropping unnecessary rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, grouping

I have a pandas dataframe as shown below. This DF contains vital information but has many unnecessary rows.

```
DF_Old =

id    tID       word   rX     rY     R
52    6         X      L-18   nan    L
52    6         X      L-12   nan    L
52    6         X      L-10   nan    L
52    7         A      N      N      nan
52    8         B      W-7    O-6    W,O
52    8         B      W-7    nan    W
52    8         B      nan    O-6    O
52    8         B      nan    nan    nan
52    8         C      W-7    O-6    W,O
52    8         C      W-7    nan    W
52    8         C      nan    O-6    O
52    8         C      nan    nan    nan
52    9         D      nan    nan    nan
```

`rX`contains the values from left to right, while `rY` contains the values from right to left. In the column `R` those values are joined while the numbers are omitted.

Some rows contain partial information and can savely be dropped. However I simply can't drop them via `DF.dropna(thresh=2)` or similar methods since I lose other (important) rows like the last row in the table. What I would like to have is a DataFrame similar to `DF_New`:

```
DF_New =

id    tID       word   r                  R
52    6         X      L-18, L-12, L-10   L
52    7         A      N                  N
52    8         B      W-7, O-6           W,O
52    8         C      W-7, O-6           W,O
52    9         D      N                  N
```

I suppose some sort of Merging (such as DF.groupby) and dropping rows is needed but all my efforts have only made this table worse. Any ideas?

Comment: I would reconsider storing comma separated values within columns as indexing, (`[...]`), searching (`query`), operating (`groupby`), and calculating (`value_counts`), even saving (`to_csv`) become much tougher!

Answer (score 0):

From your desired output is hard to reconstruct the logic you want, but this seems to be what you want

```
DF_Old= DF_Old.replace(np.nan, 'nan', regex=True)

DF_Old.groupby(['tID', 'word'])['rX'].apply(list)
```

Or

```
DF_Old(['tID', 'word'])[['rX', 'rY']].agg(lambda x : ','.join(x.unique()))
```

Comment: is this what you needed?